# Convert a basic raw SQL to Django

Tags: django, django-models

How can I convert this SQL raw query to use Django objects?

```
SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table1 
WHERE id_foo NOT IN ({ids_to_exclude}) AND bar < 1000 AND source = '{source}' 
AND created >= '{start}' AND created < '{end}'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? This is a place for question and answer, not just getting someone else to do the work.

To get you started:

```
SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table1 
WHERE id_foo NOT IN ({ids_to_exclude}) AND bar < 1000 AND source = '{source}' 
AND created >= '{start}' AND created < '{end}'
```

You should look at how to create models in django. You will need a table1 model to store your information. To create this query, you'll also need to look at the queryset aggregates (Sum) and how to use .exclude(id_in=[ids_to_exclude]).